# Append Page to Domain Name Via The Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create an input field that will allow users to input a text string that once submitted is appended to a domain name, taking the user to a page.

The process is as follows:

User inputs 'foo' into an input box. Once submit is clicked, 'foo' is prefixed by http://example.com/ and (ideally) suffixed by .html (or .php) and the browser resolves to that address, ie http://example.com/foo.html.

Is this possible? My form kung foo is (clearly) not very strong, so any help would be appreciated. With help from other Stack users I've got this far:

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 

<form id="inputbox"> <input type="text" id="addition"> <input type="submit" value="Trigger"/></form> 

<script> 
var yourForm = document.getElementById("inputbox"); 
yourForm.onsubmit = function() { 
var URLtext = document.getElementById("addition").value; 
window.location = window.location.href + URLtext; // this is for your current URL 
} 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You're setting `var yourForm = document.getElementById("inputbox")`. This targets the input element, not the form. Inputs don't have an `onsubmit`, becuase its the entire `form` that actually gets submitted. Give your form an ID, target that, and see if your event fires.

Comment: I've given the form the id of inputbox and removed it from the input field, but I get the same result.

Comment: What is that result? You never actually mention what is going wrong here.

Comment: Oh...do you not know how to trigger the submit? Add this after the your text `input`: `<input type="submit" value="Trigger"/>`. This will add a submit button to the end of your form that, when clicked, will trigger the form's submission and subsequently your function.

Comment: Also, because you moved the ID, the line where you define `URLtext` will need to be updated, because now it is looking for the value of the `form`, rather than the `input`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained the error. I just get the address in the browser with a question mark on the end (example.com/foo.html?).

Comment: in your last line, try setting `window.location` instead of `window.location.href`

Comment: Amended the original post to reflect the changes :)

Comment: flip-flop that last change - `window.location = window.location.href + URLtext;`

Comment: Still seeing the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not to use the form in general, since it will try to submit itself when the submit input is clicked. Instead, just use the two input elements and manually bind the `click` event to the submit input.

```
<input type="text" id="addition">
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="Trigger"/>

<script>
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('addition'),
        text = input.value;
    // You can further edit the input text here, (i.e. append ".html", etc)
    window.location = window.location.origin + '/' + text;

});
</script>
```

Comment: Great!  Works perfectly.  Thanks to you and @jordan-foreman.  Really appreciate it.